# Data ingestion with Apache Storm

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm, flume

I have been reading a lot of articles where implementations of Apache Storm are explained for ingesting data from either Apache Flume or Apache Kafka. My main question remains unanswered after reading several articles. What is the main benefit of using Apache Kafka or Apache Flume? Why not collecting data from a source directly into Apache Storm?

To understand this I looked into these frameworks. Correct me if I am wrong.

Apache Flume is about collecting data from a source and pushing data to a sink. The sink being in this case Apache Storm.

Apache Kafka is about collecting data from a source and storing them in a message queue until Apache Storm processes it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming you are dealing with the use case of Continuous Computation Algorithms or Real Time Analytics.

Given below is what you will have to go through if you DO NOT use Kafka or any message queue:

```
(1) You will have to implement functionality like consistency of data.

(2) You are ready to implement replication on your own

(3) You are ready to tackle a variety of failures and ready to build a fault tolerant system.

(4) You will need to create a good design so that your producer and consumer are completely decoupled.

(5) You will have to implement persistence. What happens if your consumer fails?

(6) What happens to fault resilience? Do you want to take the entire system down when your consumer fails?

(7) You will have to implement delivery guarantees as well as ordering guarantees.
```

All of the above are inherent features of a message queue (Kafka etc.) and you will of-course not like to re-invent the wheel here.

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason for having different configurations could be a matter of how the source data is obtained. Storm spouts (the first elements in the Storm topologies) are meant to *synchronously* polling for the data, while Flume agents (agent=source+channel+sink) are meant to *asynchronously* receive the data at the source. Thus, if you have a system that notifies certain events then a Flume agent is required; then this agent would be in charge of receiving the data and putting into any queue management system (ActiveMQ, RabbitMQ...) in order to be cosumed by Storm. The same would apply to Kafka.

Comment: Flume sources have two types: PollableSource and EventDrivenSources. So It is not just meant to asynchronously receive data. Storm spout can be implemented as event driven too with a little tweak. The twitter spout implementation can be an example.